# Solve StackOverflow exception

Tags: ironpython

Although I've been reading the valuable posts in StackOverflow.com, for which I am extremely greatful. I didn't have the need to create a thread of my own.

:) I always wondered what does `StackOverflow` means. Finally I was "able" to achieve this.

Does anyone have any suggestion how to fix the code below?

What I am trying to do is somehow pipe a command into new cmd process.
This is required because I need to run cmd with specific local variables.

Usually done within a batch like so `echo dir | cmd.exe`. However I would like to achieve this solely with IronPython.

Thanks in advance.

Here's example of the code:

```py
import clr

clr.AddReference("mscorlib")
import System

from System.Diagnostics import Process



""" Example"""

class P(System.Diagnostics.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        self.StartInfo.FileName = r"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
        self.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
        self.standard_input = None
        self.standard_output = None
        self.standard_error = None


    @property
    def StandardInput(self):
        return self.standard_input

    @StandardInput.getter
    def StandardInput(self):
        return self.standard_input

    @StandardInput.setter
    def StandardInput(self, val):
        self.standard_input = System.IO.StreamWriter(val)

    def Start(self):
        return self.Start()


p_instance = P()
p_instance.Start()
p_instance.StandardInput("dir")
```

Comment: Ok, I was pointed out one issue self.Start() is calling self.Start() but what should be the correct syntax here?

Comment: You should be calling the super implementation of the `Start()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JeffMercado, could you please elaborate?
Do I need to do this in a def Start(self) or under __init__(self)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically when you override a method and want to call the original implementation, you would call the super implementation. Your `Start()` function is calling itself causing the stack overflow.

```
def Start(self):
    return self.Start()
```

You need to do something like this:

```
def Start(self):
    return super(P, self).Start()
```